# How do I get all the rows before a specific index in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading an xlsx file and I want for every row to create columns based on the rows before.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_total(x):
    name = x["NAME"]
    city = x["CITY"]
    index = x.index
    records = df[df.index < index) & (df["NAME"] == name) & (df["CITY"] == city)]
    return records.size[0]

data_filename = "data.xslx"
df = pd.read_excel(data_filename, na_values=["", " ", "-"])
df["TOTAL"] = df.apply(lambda x: get_total(x), axis=1)
```

The get_total function is a simple example of what I want to achieve.

I could use `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` to get the dataframe's index as a column. I think there must be a better way to get the index of a row.

Comment: use `shift` to get the previous row

Comment: Hi, its not just the previous row. It's all the previous rows.

Comment: Use the `.name` attribute to get the current index value and then its an int `df.iloc[0: x.name]` to get all rows up to (but not including) current row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your function like this:

```
def get_total(x):
    name = x["NAME"]
    city = x["CITY"]
    index = x.name
    records df.loc[0:index]
    return records.loc[(records['NAME'] == name) & (records['CITY']==city)].size
```

the `name` attribute is the current row index value